# How do you set the to on the mail facade of Laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel, sendgrid

I am using Laravel 9.16, sendgrid 7.11, php 8.0, and the illuminate mail facade

(This code worked with the previous versions of php and sendgrid.)

Whenever I try to send an email I am getting the following error:
Email "" does not comply with addr-spec of RFC 2822.

I have broken my code into separate steps so I can see if things are being set properly.

```
$this_mailable= new WelcomeEmail($customer);
$mail_facade = Mail::to('test@gmail.com');
$mail_facade->send($this_mailable);
```

After I set the mail_facade to it looks like this:

```
$mail_facade = {Illuminate\Mail\Pending}
to = {array}
  [0] = 'test@gmail.com'
```

Yet when I call the send it returns that error (as if the to is not set)

[image]

The from is set in the mailer object which is an object inside of the facade.

[image]

When I user the default to in my development environment (similar to what I am using for the from) the email is sent so I don't believe the from is my issue.

Comment: `'test.gamil.com'` is not a valid email.

Comment: That was a typo (that I fixed) If you look at the image you can see that it is a valid email. Thanks for looking at my issue

Comment: Is the `from` email set?

Comment: I think you just need to refactor a bit; `Mail::to()` isn't likely to affect your call as written, but if you chain it like `Mail::to('test@gmail.com')->send(new WelcomeEmail($customer));` it should work (assuming `WelcomeEmail` is a Mailable class.) See the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#sending-mail. On 2nd look, that _should_ be syntactically equivalent, will do some more digging.

Comment: What you are suggesting was how I originally had my code. I broke it apart to help debug and see where my issue was. Thanks for look at my issue.

Comment: Clément Baconnier: I set the from with the .env variable MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS. I can actually get the send to work in my development environment if I set the MAIL_TO_ADDRESS to something static (which only helps in development to make sure the email is actually going through.)

Comment: Can you show the `from` section of your config/mail.php?

Comment: 'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

Comment: If you're saying this only happens on your non-development environment, can you confirm that in your `.env` file on that server has `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=something_valid@whatever.com`? Your error message suggests that either the `to` or `from` address is `''`. In `.env`, if you had `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=`, (with no value) instead of omitting it from the file, then that could cause this case. The fallback of `env('...', 'fallback')` only works if the key is not present in your `.env` file at all. Or test it via `php artisan tinker`: `env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'test') == 'test`, etc.

Comment: I have the issue in both my development and production environment. In both environments the mail will send it I set an environment variable for a MAIL_TO_ADDRESS similar to the MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS. This is why I don't think it is a configuration issue. Also it all worked before I upgraded laravel and php.  I believe I am not setting the to correctly but the documentation seems to suggest that you can just send an email string to the to field.

Answer (score 0):

I think as Tim Lewis mentioned in the comment above should work, what you will need is to get the user email before actually selecting the Mailable class that you want to work with!

```
<?php 
     $user = User::find($id);
     Mail::to($user->email)
           ->send(new WelcomeEmail($customer))
           ->subject('Welcome to my application');
```

Correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: The `to()` method of `Mail::to()` expects a valid email address as a string, not an integer as `$user->id` would be, so this is not correct, and if you used `$user->email`, then it's the same as `::to('test@gmail.com')`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I will fix it!

Comment: You _can_ fix it with `$user->email` as suggested, but I'm still not sure that will fix the issue here; the more and more I read/dig into it, the more likely this is just a configuration issue. The original asker will have to confirm though. Cheers for the answer attempt still 

Comment: This is similar to what my original code looked like. I just replaced the $user->email with an actual email string literal to simply the question and leave out the possiblity that the variable didn't contain a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

This was such a dumb mistake but I wanted to post in case anyone else would make the same mistake.
I had code in the config/mail.php file that would set the global to email. (reading it from my .env file)
When I didn't have a variable in the .env file it would try to override the email I was sending in the to with a null value for the global to.